# POSTMAN 400 Bad request and on : http://localhost:5000/api/register a have:{"success":false,"msg":"Page not founded"}

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, postman, mern

I am learning the MERN stack and trying to create a SIGN IN and SIGN UP register with email verification. I am stuck with this error and can't see where I am wrong. PLEASE HELP!
Here is part of my code on the server-side:
I am learning the MERN stack and trying to create a SIGN IN and SIGN UP register with email verification. I am stuck with this error and can't see where I am wrong. PLEASE HELP!
Here is part of my code on the server-side:

auth.models.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const crypto = require('crypto');
// user schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true
    },
    hashed_password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: 'subscriber'
    },
    resetPasswordLink: {
      data: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

db.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
    const connection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${connection.connection.host}`);
}; 

module.exports = connectDB;
```

server.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
// Config dotev
require('dotenv').config({
    path: './config/config.env'
})


const app = express()

// Connect to database
connectDB();

// body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// Load routes
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth.route')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Dev Logginf Middleware
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(cors({
        origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL
    }))
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

// Use Routes
app.use('/api', authRouter)

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        msg: "Page not founded"
    })
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

config.env

```js
PORT=5000
NODE_ENV=development
CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3000
MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/server
```

Screen from POSTMAN:
[image]

Comment: That's a lot of code! Can you give us a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I edited my code.. Thank's for your time.